# I want to exchange data between my Android application and my web site

Tags: java, android, spring, rest, web-services

Android web view is not what i looking for.Android interface is completely different from the web view.Do I want to make my Web and Android app to use REST web services? I am designing my web using springMVC.

Comment: Create webservice using spring mvc `RestController` annotation and `responsebody`

Answer (score 0):

What data are you expecting to exchange from and to the website? Does this mean you will be adding, deleting, updating the data or just simply retrieving

Regardless I would look at Json data if your website is capable of providing that. If Yes, I would recommend using retrofit to download the data onto your application and use it however you like. Retrofit is also capable of working in conjunction with CRUD methods as well.